# Add only new items from listbox to SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, duplicates, listbox, new-item

i have a listbox that users can add Countries Names into it anytime.
now i need to only add new data to check if the data is new then insert it to sql.
my code not work:

```vb
For Each i As String In listbox1.Items
    Dim sql = "select * From Countries where CountryName=N'" & i & "'"
    Dim adp As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, SQlconn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    adp.Fill(ds)
    Dim dt = ds.Tables(0)
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Dim dr = dt.NewRow
        dr!CountryName = i
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(adp)
        adp.Update(dt)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: How did the country names that aren't new get in there? Were they also added by the user or were they retrieved from the database?

Comment: The code above is for save button, the country names added by the user from textbox.

Comment: Also i load the listbox items from database in form_load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're loading the existing names from the database in the first place then there's no need for you to check anything. Simply query the database to populate a `DataTable` and bind that to the `ListBox`. When the user adds a new country, add it to the `DataTable` and it will automatically show up in the `ListBox`. When it's time to save, just use the same data adapter to save the `DataTable` and only the new records will be saved.